# Examine the partial and total differentiability of $\displaystyle f(x,y):=\sqrt[3]{x^3+y^3}$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, multivariable-calculus

Examine the partial and total differentiability of $\displaystyle f(x,y):=\sqrt[3]{x^3+y^3}$

I know that if a function is total differentiable than it is also partial differentiable. Do I have to start with the total differentiation?

For partial differentiation I get:$f_x = x^2(x^3+y^3)^{-\frac{2}{3}}$

The definiton of total differentiability the definition is: $$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (a,b)}\frac{f(x,y)-(A(x-a)+B(y-b)+f(a,b))}{\sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2}}=0$$

In which way can I continue it?

Comment: Continuous partial derivatives could imply total differentiability, check [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/801445/continuous-partial-derivative-implies-total-differentiable-check)

Comment: You partial derivatives are continuous wherever $x^3 + y^3 \ne 0$, so $f$ is differentiable whenever $y \ne -x$. So the only problem is at points of the form $(a,-a)$. When $a \ne 0$, you can check, using the definition of the derivative as a limit, that neither partial derivative exists. At $(0,0)$, both partial derivatives exist, as do all directional derivatives, but the directional derivatives are not what would be expected if the function were differentiable there, taking into account the values of the partial derivatives.